Vercel Deployment: FUNCTION_INVOCATION_TIMEOUT Error on POST Request, but GET Request Works Fine
I recently deployed my Node.js backend to Vercel using the free version. The deployment was successful, and the GET endpoints are working perfectly fine. However, when I try to hit the POST /register endpoint, I get the following error:

An error occurred with your deployment
FUNCTION_INVOCATION_TIMEOUT

What could be the reason behind this error? Is there a specific timeout setting in Vercel that I need to adjust, or could there be an issue with my backend code that causes this timeout?
Register endpoint

Get endpoint

I tried sending a POST request to the /register endpoint using Postman. I expected the server to process the registration and return a success response. However, instead of the expected response, I encountered the FUNCTION_INVOCATION_TIMEOUT error. I checked the GET endpoints, and they are working correctly without any issues.
